# In C BNF, UnaryOperator ::= ( "&" | "*" | "+" | "-" | "~" | "!" ). Why / and % are excluded in UnaryOperator?

Tags: c, bnf, unary-operator, binary-operators

In C BNF, `MultiplicativeExpression` and `UnaryOperator` are defined like the following:

> ```
> MultiplicativeExpression ::= CastExpression ( ( "*" | "/" | "%" ) MultiplicativeExpression )?
> UnaryOperator ::= ( "&" | "*" | "+" | "-" | "~" | "!" )
> ```

Are `/` and `%` defined in `MultiplicativeExpression`?

Comment: What is C BNF? C standard?

Comment: @SouravGhosh ,that is C's Backus-Naur Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation)

> a unary operation is an operation with **only one** operand..

So, the operators which needs or works on only one operand, are unary operators.

`%` and `/` definitely needs two operands, so they are not unary operators.

In case, you're wondering about the presence of `+` and `-`, they are unary positive and negative operators (*unary arithmetic operators*), not addition and subtractions.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.3

> The result of the unary `+` operator is the value of its (promoted) operand. The integer
>   promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

and

> The result of the unary `-` operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer
>   promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

Comment: Is there + represents plus which a plus b?

Comment: unary + and binary + are different operators

Answer (score 1):

Some characters are used for more than one operator. `*` is used for both the multiplication operator (which is a binary operator) and the address indirection operator (which is a unary operator).  Thus, you can have an expression like

```
x = a * *p; // multiply a by what p points to
```

`%` and `/` do not have a similar use in unary expressions, which is why they don't appear in the list of unary operators.

`&` is another character that can be used as a unary operator (address-of) or a binary operator (bitwise `and`).

Answer (score 0):

`/` and `%` never exist in contexts that take just one operand so therefore they are never *unary operators*.
As for the other operators given:

1. `&` can mean address-of (as well as bitwise AND)
2. `*` can mean pointer dereference (as well as multiplication).
3. `+` and `-` can be unary plus / minus.
4. `!` and `~` are logical negation and bitwise complement.